# Has Superman ever used his heat vision to cook food?

Tags: dc, superman

Superman's heat vision is a cool tool that allows him to project rays of energy (IR, X-Ray,or whatever the writers come up with) over an [undefined](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91068/does-supermans-heat-vision-have-a-maximum-range) range. He has used it for many great (and not so great) feats, including [melting glaciers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12617/when-was-supermans-first-use-of-heat-vision), [shaving](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5394/how-does-superman-shave) and [leaving writings on walls](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99279/can-post-crisis-superman-destroy-the-world-with-his-heat-vision).

There is one more use one can think of for such a versatile power: cooking! Has Superman ever used his heat vision to cook (not his enemies!) food?

Comment: In the *Everyday Heroes* webcomic, Summer tries to defrost a chicken in a few seconds with her heat vision, with disastrous results.  http://eheroes.smackjeeves.com/comics/1891177/chain-of-events/

Comment: “There is one more use one can think of for such a versatile power” — just one?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite well, there's also [this](https://xkcd.com/378/).

Comment: Forget Heat Vision... Meat Vision is my superhero power of choice.

Comment: In my youth I had a superman comic from the 1960s or 1970s where Superman travels in time to ancient Rome and invents popcorn, which is cooked with his heat vision.

Comment: @Eric post it as an answer and ride the wave of up votes with us :D

Comment: I seem to recall an episode of, I think it was New Adventures of Superman where Louis and Clark were having guests over, but the food was undercooked. Clark heatvisioned it up a bit, but couldn't turn the vision off, so the meal was ruined. Red kryptonite was mentioned as a possible cause, but I don't remember anything else from the episode. It was a lot of years ago.

Comment: There was also an episode of Smallville (I don't know if that counts as a version of Superman to you) where Clark used his heat vision to speed toast some bread, but I forget which season and episode it occurred in.

Comment: General Zod and Company fried a rattle snake in the second movie - does that count?  Technically cooked, and it is food...

Answer (score 41):

There are two examples that I know of:

- In the epilogue of *Kingdom Come*, the Trinity meets in a cafe. Bruce orders **"Steak. Well-done."**, but the steak he's brought is not even "a shade over medium". Instead of calling for a waiter, Clark decides to make himself useful for once:

  [image: Bruce prepares to call the waitress; Clark uses his heat vision to cook the steak thoroughly]
- In a deleted scene from *Superman II* (1980), with Christopher Reeve, titular hero uses his heat vision to cook a soufflé in his Fortress of Solitude:

Comment: I didn't even realize that was a deleted scene. They must've added it back to some other cut that I watched.

Comment: Doesn't Dean Cain do it in Lois and Clark at one point too?

Comment: @Chris no idea what you're talking about, since I haven't seen this film

Comment: Clark should have zapped blasted Bruce for ordering his steak well done and put him out of his misery.

Comment: That's not a deleted scene.  It was in the original release of _Superman II_.  Not sure if it's also in the Richard Donner recut version.

Answer (score 31):

In the (rightfully) maligned *Superman IV*, Superman and Clark Kent somehow end up on a sort of double date with Lois Lane and Lacy Warfied (played by Mariel Hemingway), at the latter's apartment.  He has to distract the two women so he can change back and forth, and one way he does this is using his heat vision on the roast in the oven.  It starts smoking, and Lacy runs to deal with it, finding it perfectly cooked when she pulls it out.

[image]

Comment: wouldnt he burn the door first?

Comment: @lois6b must be something between x-rays and heat vision... I'd call it microwave vision!

Comment: @Graipher: The oven in the gif is a regular oven, not a microwave oven.

Comment: @raznagul Ah, you are right. Somehow it looked very small, which my brain immediately associated with it being a microwave oven.

Comment: @lois6b If it was focussed from a large area to a small one, it would only heat the door up a bit. Perhaps Superman can warp the path that light travels in some way... (Gravity manipulation, anyone?)

Comment: @lois6b Superman can of course create an Einstein-Rosen bridge across Spacetime.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Early 1960s]
Here's a comic cover from the early 1960s. Another cover featured a one-shot character, Superman Junior, who roasted hot dogs with his xray vison as Superman (Sr.) chilled lemonade with his super-breath.

Comment: Haha :D Brilliant!

Answer (score 8):

In Smallville episode 207 ("Lineage"), Clark uses heat vision to toast a slice of bread

[image]

In Smallville episode 420 ("Ageless"), Clark uses heat vision to warm a bottle of baby formula

[image]